# How to see an image that has just been uploaded to server

Tags: html, spring, image, input, upload

Here is my problem, on the front end, I have the following simple input file:

```
 <input id="input-file" type="file" name="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" onchange="uploadFile();"/>
```

then this is the code for uploadFile

```
  function uploadFile() {
let file = document.getElementById("input-file").files[0];
alert(file);
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", file);

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:8080/uploadme", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => {
      let cont = document.getElementById("cont");
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = result;
    cont.appendChild(img);
   })
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
```

on the back end I have Spring Boot controller transferring the file to a publicly accessible folder and send back the path via `ResponseEntity`

```
private final String imgpath = <the full path to my java spring boot project folder> + "\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\img";
 @PostMapping("/uploadme")
  public ResponseEntity<String> uploadModel( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String message = "";
    String path = imgpath + "/" + file.getOriginalFilename();
    try {
      System.out.println(path);
      File uploadedFile = new File(path);
      file.transferTo(uploadedFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
return ResponseEntity.ok("/img/" + file.getOriginalFilename());
  }
```

and what happens is that I select the file, to upload, it's read so the alert(file) says `[file object]`

but it does not show it, and when I look at console it shows a 404 not found error. But the file is there, when I check it, it's just that the browser doesn't see it at all.

I want the user to see the image that has been just uploaded after the upload is complete, but no matter what I do, the image is not shown, even though, the path is correct.

Any help would be appreciated.